# Field repository in com.petar.demoreferrals.service.impl.UserServiceImpl required a bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying one basic spring boot demo. 
I am getting this error.

...

I don't know which code to copy so here is link from the demo https://github.com/PetarRistevski/demo-referrals

This is what I get 
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field repository in com.petar.demoreferrals.service.impl.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.petar.demoreferrals.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.petar.demoreferrals.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `@Profile(“jpa”)` from `UserRepository` or you need to set "jpa" in "spring.profiles.default" property like:

`spring.profiles.default=jpa`

Issue is: you are creating `UserRepository` when profile is "jpa" but you haven’t  add "jpa" to spring profiles. So spring have not created bean for `UserRepository`.